# Modifying CocoaGL example

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to use the CocoaGL example provided by Apple to start off with a openGL application. I decided to this one because it already implements all user interactions for camera rotation, zoom, ....

However, I can not really wrap my head around where to load data from disk. In the example the cube is drawn in BasicOpenGLView.m -> drawCube .
I want to load data into memory and display it at runtime. Where would I squeeze in a load function. I would have to provide a pointer to my data-array to the drawCube / drawData function so that modelview & projectionMatrix can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

can't find the sample code that you mention but you should be able to inject any data that you want provided that it adheres to how opengl expects the data to come in. so if the cube in the demo has vertex and vertex color your data should as well. if yours has for example vertex normal and texture cords and it expects vertex and vertex color then you might need to fudge with the render states or even change your shader programs if you are not using the fixed function pipeline.
check this course out maybe it will help.
https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291

Comment: sorry I came back so late, here's the link to the sample I was talking about. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: so there are few vars there that you can over write (load from disk)
cube_num_vertices
cube_vertices
cube_vertex_colors
num_faces
cube_faces